# how to make uiview movable?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview

I am developing a simple game photo puzzle. I have 9 pieces of an image. The image parts are placed on different UIView. Now I want to know how can I move the uiview parts on a touch ?

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check [this](http://www.ifans.com/forums/showthread.php?t=135280)
you need to handle

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {}  

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {}
```

events